# Retrieving database info while requesting other data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am not sure how to fix this issues.
Basicly, I need to be enable to retrieve data from a database.
But this needs to be limited to the users account plan. 
For example: an user has a membership plan, which comes with 5 emails. 
He will need to be enable to see 5 emails, instead of my whole email database getting extracted.

Code:

```
$SQLSelect = $odb -> query("SELECT * FROM `accounts` ORDER BY `ID` DESC LIMIT = '" . ($_POST['email']) . "'");
```

Comment: So set limit of 5 if the user has limited plan ?

Comment: It needs to match the users account, so it's not global. Every user can have a different plan.

Comment: So if I POST `"; DROP TABLE accounts` to that `email` variable, what happens?

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: @Jeff then do not hardcode `5` but have a schema for this e.g. `$userInfo->getPlan()->getEmailLimit()` method should return the limit, and you put it in to the query...

Comment: How do I put it in the query? Sorry, I am new to php ect.

Comment: The simpliest explanation is `if ($userPlan == 'limited') { $limitEmails = 5; } else { $limitEmails = 100; }` and then in the sql `LIMIT $limitEmails`

Comment: @RoyalBg I got this:                         $limited = $row['emails'];
                        $SQLSelect = $odb -> query("SELECT * FROM `accounts` ORDER BY `ID` DESC LIMIT = $limited");

Answer (score 0):

Desc limit is option what allows to display limited amount.
Example:
You have table with 5 rows and those rows have auto increment id.
wtih select * from users order by id desc limit 3, you will select users with id 1 , 2 , 3 because at begining you order it by id, so it select 1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5 and then u say that you need only 3 of them using desc limit. So it seems like you got desc limit wrong...

If i got your example then you need something like this :

```
$limit = 5;
query("SELECT * FROM `accounts` ORDER BY `ID` DESC LIMIT = ".$limit)
```

So here user will only see accounts with id 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 and 5.
If i didn't say what you need, i rly didn't get your question

Comment: Hi, the $limit variable needs to retrieve the user his membership from the database. (Membership is called: "amail") with the data retrieved from "amail", it needs to limit the select query.